# How to Define and Select JPEG Q-tables Using Pillow (PIL)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, jpeg, image-compression, quantization

I'm currently studying the image compression. I've found in PIL ([documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.2.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html)) that by using the *im.save* function and by customizing the *qtables* I can reduce the image size. The question is how to generate these tables and select the best ones in Python to provide better compression ratio?

It's also said that there must be between 2 and 4 tables. The first one I guess is 
the "Luminance Quantization Table" and the second is "Chrominance Quantization Table". And what are the others?

I'd be grateful for any information on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Quantization is a compression process that is used reduce the amount of high frequency data in an image. The idea here being that human vision is not very good at distinguishing very bright (or dark) colors.

This is done by dividing the [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform) coefficients (A matrix, representing the frequency domain) by a quantization matrix and rounding the resulting values to integers.

> Quantized DCT Coefficients = Round( DCT Coefficients / Quantization Matrix )

Generally, as you approach the bottom right of a quantization table you'll find the values increase. This is because the frequency increases as you approach the bottom right of the DCT coefficients and the high frequency values are what we want to sacrifice to increase compression. The resulting quantized DCT coefficients will contain many zeros, particularly in the bottom right (where the high frequency data was). The quantized DCT coefficients are set up to be compressed by an entropy encoding that utilizes the repeating zeros.

```
Image.save('pathto.jpeg', qtables= <integer between 0-100> )
# Where 0 is worst and 95 is best. 100 will disable some of the compression.
# These values represent tables based on Section K.1 of the JPEG specification
# Other options: web_low, web_medium, web_high, web_very_high, 
# web_maximum, low, medium, high, maximum

# To retrieve an image's Q-tables use (returns a Dictionary with each table as a list):
with Image.open('pathto.jpeg') as im:
    qtable_dict = im.quantization
# qtable_dict = {[<64 integers>],[<64 integers>]}
# A dictionary in this format can be provided to the qtables arg
# to save an image with specific Q-tables
```

In general, when creating Q-tables high values increase compression and decrease the image quality. The more zeros in the Quantized DCT coefficients the more they can be compressed by an entropy encoding.

There is at least one Q-table in a JPEG. The first is for the Luminance component, the second is for one or both color components, and the third (usually a duplicate of the second) is for the other color component.

The rounding part of the Quantization step is lossy which means information is permanently lost. However, wherever there is a 1 in a Q-table the coefficient is divided by 1 so no information is lost.

---

There is another step in JPEG compression that has a big imapact on the image size called Downsampling (aka chroma subsampling). This typically occurs a few steps before Quantization. Downsampling in JPEG compression is based on the idea that brightness is more impactful to human vision than color. This is done by encoding less color information than luminance information, the amount is defined by a ratio `#:#:#`.

```
Image.save('pathto.jpeg', subsampling= <integer between 0-2> )
# 0: 4:4:4
# 1: 4:2:2
# 2: 4:2:0
```

Where, [Y':Cb:Cr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr) (Luminance : Blue Component : Red Component).

Huffman encoding is a type of entropy encoding (lossless compression) which essentially takes the repeating zeros generated by the quantization and creates smaller packages to represent them. This is typically one of the last steps in JPEG compression.

```
# You can use stream type to save with or without Huffman tables
# But there doesn't appear to be an arg for switching to a different encoding
Image.save('pathto.jpeg', streamtype= <integer between 0-2> )
```

Additionally, there are a few [JPEG compression formats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26530897/19538445). Each affecting image size and encoding/decoding speed.

```
# The following saves a progressive jpeg
# the only difference between baseline and progressive is the number of tables
Image.save('pathto.jpeg', progressive=True)
```